# Swift3, Got message from using SDK

Tags: ios, swift, sdk

When I try to use one framework, I got this message.

```
2017-07-13 15:51:17.966401+0700 testApp[44963:11841246] SDK Version : 1.2.6_20170419
2017-07-13 15:51:22.572884+0700 testApp[44963:11841267] libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 44963 (testApp) does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled
2017-07-13 15:51:22.572933+0700 testApp[44963:11841267] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:550: no access to InverseDeviceID (see <rdar://problem/11744455>)
2017-07-13 15:51:23.182125+0700 testApp[44963:11841298] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process testApp
2017-07-13 15:51:23.182506+0700 testApp[44963:11841298] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
     filterBlacklist =     (
     );
     filterWhitelist =     (
     );
     restrictWeb = 1;
     useContentFilter = 0;
     useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
     whitelistEnabled = 0;
  }
2017-07-13 15:51:23.182586+0700 testApp[44963:11841298] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
```

I try to research but I have no idea what it is

Comment: It looks like some logging from the SDK you are using and should not have any further importance. Which framework are you using?

Comment: Getting these logs on crash?It seems there is an issue with app signing.Please check https://github.com/calabash/run_loop/issues/238.Hope it might be relevant to your problem,

Comment: @Thomas Framework from my company. Thank you for saving my time!. It's log from SDK

Comment: @Ellen thank you for your answer